# PHP Hash raw_output format

Tags: php, hash

What is the exact format of output in Hash when raw_output = true ?

Is it binary (some 1 and 0)? 
Is it unicode char ? 
something else ?

Do you know how I can reproduce hash("sha512","test",true) in iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server based and doesnt matter on with device the output will display.

if hash raw_outputs is true like

```
echo hash("sha512","test",true);
```

u will get something like this:

```
î&°ÝJ÷çIª�ãÁ
é�?a��w.G?�¥Ô�
²zÁ�ø áÕøO�¼�Ö{72ÃÌ_©­�oWõ(¨ÿ
```

so the answer is: u will get unicode and much more binary chars as output.